# Install screen doesn't show on Ubuntu LiveCD/LiveUSB

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, live-cd

I got a new PC about a year ago and back then I tried to install Ubuntu beside Windows 7. I used my 3 month (back then) old CD I used to successfully install on my old computer beside of Windows XP. However in this computer, the CD itself boots fine and I can see the background and cursor. But the install screen does not show. It seems to freeze there. Same thing with USB driver. Well I recently started doing some tiny game developing and thought to port my game to Linux too. But now after getting the most recent ISO and mounting it on USB drive, same thing. Background and cursor but that's it.

My computer is a Fujitsu Esprimo Mobile v6555 and specs are enough for Ubuntu.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Ubuntu Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download)
It's a non-graphical installer but the end-result is the same.

Comment: Thank you so much. After some bitching with defragmenting and partioining, then needing to use recovery mode and so on. I finaly have dual boot ubuntu and windows 7 :D

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

before installing there is a place to add some options (unfortunately do not remember where exactly, but definitely before installation, should be somewhere from when it shows the boot menu)

add this

```
nomodeset noapic noacpi
```