# Ubuntu 12.04 install screen doesn't appear on fujitsu v6555

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

I have a Fujitsu v6555 with enough specs to run ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which is currently running Windows 7.

When I put the Ubuntu live DVD (`ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso`), it starts booting then shows the background and mouse cursor and freezes!

No installation screen showing further , it just stays a background with a mouse cursor.

I searched relevant asked questions here and tried pressing <kbd>f6</kbd> at the boot menu and checking the (acpi = off) but the result went worse , when i clicked try ubuntu , a black screen with underscore flashing at upper left corner appeared.

I found another similar question: [Install screen doesn't show on Ubuntu LiveCD/LiveUSB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53645/install-screen-doesnt-show-on-ubuntu-livecd-liveusb)

I didn't understand what is the Ubuntu alternative CD? And what is the network installer. It's just a link with files and folders. It got me lost.

Please help I want Ubuntu so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you will need to patch DSDT afterwards ;) (mines patched) ok first! don't disable ACPI! .. it wont boot at all!.. the problem is Nouveau! you need to boot the minimal PC and install without graphical installation.. there is no other install method except 10.04 as this boots to live desktop.. ok so boot minimal pc and once installation is complete boot to single user and grab the latest drivers off nVidia.. install them and you are good to go! boot into the standard kernel.. there is a brightness issue so boot with acpi_backlight=vendor, google acpi_video0 and you will find guides and fixes about that.. I have Debian Wheezy installed.

Comment: forgot to say! blacklist Nouveau before installing the nVidia drivers or so a $sudo apt-get remove --purge nouveau* .. download the minimal / alternate CD and burn the ISO to a DVD

Comment: Edit your answer to include additional information instead of adding a comment.